# compile error when converting string of numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, generics

In my code I am getting a lot of numbers that are separated by a space. So for example I am getting 318 numbers and I need to put them in an array. 
So I did this:

```
int[] alleNummers = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(new[] { ' ' }), int.Parse);
```

but when I filled this length of numbers in:

```
4 1 3 3 4 6 10 1 1 8 7 1 8 6 11 9 2 6 9 1 8 2 12 9 12 1 3 1 6 8 6 10 9 9 1 1 2 11 2 2 6 8 3 1 1 2 10 3 7 6 3 3 7 2 11 7 2 2 7 8 10 1 6 6 9 7 7 11 5 8 1 10 3 3 11 4 4 8 6 11 2 8 1 9 10 12 3 12 1 10 8 11 11 1 4 8 7 10 6 11 6 7 9 8 10 8 11 1 4 5 12 5 1 1 1 10 12 4 10 1 2 5 11 12 6 3 7 1 1 1 12 6 7 9 2 4 4 12 5 7 5 5 12 5 5 12 3 5 4 12 5 5 5 4 4 10 7 11 10 7 12 10 1 7 6 2 11 10 2 4 4 6 8 4 11 1 3 1 5 7 1 9 11 5 1 3 3 7 2 1 1 1 10 1 8 3 3 6 12 4 10 4 9 5 7 8 6 10 8 10 4 9 7 3 1 7 6 4 1 7 4 2 8 1 3 3 4 5 9 4 9 6 8 6 11 2 1 4 12 9 1 4 5 8 7 6 2 12 9 3 6 12 5 1 1 8 4 4 1 12 8 9 6 3 2 5 5 3 8 4 11 9 8 3 4 2 8 6 2 5 9 7 4 1 8 5 9 12 8 9 12 3 6 5 6 8 9 10 10 5 2 8 1 9 10 5 11 6 10 12 10 6 7 2 7 2 6 3.
```

I am getting `system.formatexception: Input string was not in a correct format.`
I looked around the internet and I saw I needed to change my code to this:

```
int[] alleNummers = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(new[] { ' ' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), int.Parse);
```

But now I am not getting all the numbers and I have no idea why this is happening. When I filled the above numbers in, `alleNummers.Count` give me 115 and not 318.

I would like to know why this is happing and what I should do to get these numbers in an array or in any `collections.generic class`.

Comment: You might have got two spaces in series. best is you can remove the space from the string first and then move to an array..

Comment: Rather than testing this by typing into the console, test it by assigning the test data to a string and use that in place of the `Console.ReadLine()`. If you can reproduce the problem that way, post the entire program here.

Comment: For me the first code compiles and runs just fine and retrurns 318 items. Are you sure your input looks like this? You may have an error on any of those numbers, e.g. something like `3.5`.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your code, I think it's the max length of ReadLine being around 256.  So it only reads the first 115 numbers (and including spaces, meets the max length).  Are you pasting all those numbers into the console?  If so, do you see them all after you paste them in.

Comment: Based on what @dustmouse said what do you get when calling `Console.ReadLine().Length`? How long is the string you´ve inputted and how long is the string that is recognizes from the console? Anyway it is not clear why you manually want to input such a huge list of numbers, riscing many typing-mistakes.

Comment: @dustmouse I didn't know readline() had a max. Is there any other method that I could use that is able to go higher than 256 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As dustmouse already pointed out the max length of characters you may enter to the console is 256. So what you *actually* enter is the following:

```
4 1 3 3 4 6 10 1 1 8 7 1 8 6 11 9 2 6 9 1 8 2 12 9 12 1 3 1 6 8 6 10 9 9 1 1 2 11 2 2 6 8 3 1 1 2 10 3 7 6 3 3 7 2 11 7 2 2 7 8 10 1 6 6 9 7 7 11 5 8 1 10 3 3 11 4 4 8 6 11 2 8 1 9 10 12 3 12 1 10 8 11 11 1 4 8 7 10 6 11 6 7 9 8 10 8 11 1 4 5 12 5 1 1 1
```

which are the first 256 characters from your input string (notice the trailing space). As the last character is a space you´ll get the `FormatException` you mentioned because `String.Split` will return 115 array-elements including an empty one at the end which cannot be converted to int. This is also why `String.Split` with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` set works because it simply omits the empty element from the array to be converted to int.

As long as you enter all those numbers using the console you´re stuck on this limitation of characters. What you can do however is read this input from a file or any other kind of stream:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(fileName));
int[] alleNummers = Array.ConvertAll(text.Split(new[] { ' ' }), int.Parse);
```